# Use email templates with node.js + sendgrid

Tags: node.js, email, templates, sendgrid

I am building an app using node.js and using sendgrid to handle my emails. Does anyone know of a way I can define an email template that can be used in the email's body?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6):

Sendgrid docs detail how to create your template [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/create-and-edit-transactional-templates/), and if you're looking to send the template via node, you'll need Sendgrid Mail (not to be confused with Sendgrid Client), there's an example of how to send your template [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the @sendgrid/mail library:

```
  const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const msg = {
    to: "recipientmail", 
    from: "verifiedsendermail",
    subject: "Email Subject",
    template_id: "your sendgrid email dynamic template id",
    personalizations: [
      {
        dynamic_template_data: {
          fullName: "John Doe",
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then((response: any) => {
     
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      
    });
```

Here, your template would look like the following, where {{fullName}} is your dynamic variable:
[image]

Comment: You can use - https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#handlebarjs-reference

Answer (score 1):

try the below code:

Mailer.js

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
templates = {
    password_reset_confirm: "d-a02ad738dfc8404c8da016b46a7548sd",
    password_reset        : "d-e779dcfad71b47e7be8d79bdfe75fb0c",
    confirm_account       : "d-68c570dd12044d894e07566bf951964",
};
function sendEmail(data) {
   const msg = {
      //extract the email details
      to: data.receiver,
      from: data.sender,
      templateId: templates[data.templateName],
      //extract the custom fields 
      dynamic_template_data: {
         name: data.name,
         confirm_account_url:  data.confirm_account__url,
         reset_password_url: data.reset_password_url
      }
    };
    //send the email
    sgMail.send(msg, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          console.log("That's wassup!");
      }
    });
}
exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;
```

Driver.js

```
//import the mailer.js file we previously created
var sender = require("./mailer.js");
var data = {
   //name of the email template that we will be using
   templateName: "confirm_account",
   //sender's and receiver's email
   sender: "abc@xyz.com",
   receiver: "xyz@abc.com",   
   //name of the user
   name: "Arjun Bastola",
   //unique url for the user to confirm the account
   confirm_account_url: "www.veniqa.com/unique_url"
   
};
//pass the data object to send the email
sender.sendEmail(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [sendgrid-nodejs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs) library then you can find an example of how to specify a template in the [readme](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#templates). You can also find more high-level [transactional email template](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Transactional_Templates/index.html) information in the docs.

Comment: can you post an example to use it?

Comment: Information is here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/78dae9ed05cc54bd50b4c0354a5e15855d83db60/docs/use-cases/transactional-templates.md